# Error during installation of mysql client in Mac Os

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

So I am trying to install MySQL client in my Mac Os Catalina but I get the following error.

"  MySQLdb/_mysql.c:29:10: fatal error: 'mysql.h' file not found
#include "mysql.h" "

I have installed Mysql using this XAMPP stuff in Mac. When I do "which MySQL" it can find the correct path. What can it be the error?

Comment: Why don’t you use MAMP?

Comment: Xamp is the same as mamp and wamp. It’s only for the three different OS. x=linux, M=macOS, W=Windows. All three packages are doing the same. They install Webserver, php and database on you computer